# Force Auto Submission of Google Form after X Minutes after opening.

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am looking for a way to use Google Forms for tests. I want to be able to send a form link out and have people work on it for X amount of time. After the time period has elapsed I want to have the form auto submitted.

There are a few posts about this same topic but none seem to provide any help.

Comment: You could probably do something like that with a standard html form by using the setTimeout function.  In chrome you can actually pass parameters to the setTimeout function.  So I'm guessing you could pass an object which contains all of the answers to the questions.  But I don't think you can accomplish that with Google Forms.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to auto submit a Google Form response after any amount of time after opening. This, because there is not a built-in way to add a script to the response view of a Google Form.